# Using sed on line break element

Tags: linux, sed

Hello let say I have a file such as :

```
$OUT some text
some text 
some text
$OUT
$OUT
$OUT
```

how can I use sed in order to replace the 3 `$OUT` into `"replace-thing"` ?

and get

```
$OUT some text
some text 
some text
replace-thing
```

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26284/how-can-i-use-sed-to-replace-a-multi-line-string

Comment: What have you tried? Pro tip: It's easy to do (and memory consuming) with GNU sed with `sed -z`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With sed:

```sh
sed -n '1h; 1!H; ${g; s/\$OUT\n\$OUT\n\$OUT/replace-thing/g; p;}' file
```

GNU sed does not require the semicolon after `p`.

With commentary

```sh
sed -n '    # without printing every line:
    # next 2 lines read the entire file into memory
    1h      # line 1, store current line in the hold space
    1!H     # not line 1, append a newline and current line to hold space

    # now do the search-and-replace on the file contents
    ${      # on the last line:
        g   # replace pattern space with contents of hold space
        s/\$OUT\n\$OUT\n\$OUT/replace-thing/g   # do replacement
        p   # and print the revised contents
    }
' file
```

This is the main reason I only use sed for very simple things: once you start using the lesser-used commands, you need extensive commentary to understand the program.

Note the commented version does not work on the BSD-derived sed on MacOS -- the comments break it, but removing them is OK.

---

In plain bash:

```sh
pattern=$'$OUT\n$OUT\n$OUT'      # using ANSI-C quotes
contents=$(< file)
echo "${contents//$pattern/replace-thing}"
```

And the perl one-liner:

```sh
perl -0777 -pe 's/\$OUT(\n\$OUT){2}/replace-thing/g' file
```

Answer (score 2):

for this particular task, I recommend to use [awk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/) instead. (hope that's an option too)

Update: to replace all 3 `$OUT` use: (Thanks to @thanasisp and @glenn jackman)

```
cat input.txt | awk '
BEGIN {
    i = 0
    p = "$OUT" # Pattern to match
    n = 3 # N matches
    r = "replace-thing"
}

$0 == p {
    ++i
    if(i == n){
        print(r)
        i = 0 #reset counter (optional)
    }
}

$0 != p {
    i = 0
    print($0)
}'
```

If you just want to replace the 3th `$OUT` usage, use:

```
cat input.txt | awk '
BEGIN {
    i = 0
    p = "\\$OUT" # Pattern to match
    n = 3 # Nth match
    r = "replace-thing"
}

$0 ~ p {
    ++i
    if(i == n){
        print(r)
    }
}

i <= n || $0 !~ p {
    print($0)
}'
```

Comment: Hmm, this doesn't give the expected output: it replaces the *third* $OUT line only.

Comment: Oh yes you are right... shame on me, I did not read the question carefully..

Comment: You have to reset `i` for every row not matching, or else you print `r` after `n` random occurences of `p`, but they should be sequential occurences.

Comment: You're right @thanasisp, another miss understanding of the question. @chippycentra wanted to replace all of the 3 `$OUT` . Shame on me again.... I will update my solution asap..

Comment: Also here the pattern is the whole line, you have to test for `$0 == p` (see that `~` will match first line of sample too). Also use just p="$OUT".

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E ':a;N;s/[^\n]*/&/3;Ta;/^(\$OUT\n?){3}$/d;P;D' file
```

Gather up 3 lines in the pattern space and if those 3 lines each contain `$OUT`, delete them. Otherwise, print/delete the first line and repeat.